# How to use createBottomTabNavigator inside another React component

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am updating the old react-native project to a new one and I am getting

> **Invariant Violation: The navigation prop is missing for this navigator...**

error now. But I don't know how to use `createBottomTabNavigator` inside another component in the latest react-navigation version.

Any help is appreciated!

```html
renderModel() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Dummy Sample</Text>
      <GeoResult /> // this is createBottomTabNavigator.
    </View>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my example on implementing createBottomTabNavigator inside React Component

note: i am using react-navigation version 3.3.0

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'
import FirstTab from './tabs/FirstTab';
import SecondTab from './tabs/SecondTab';
import ThirdTab from './tabs/ThirdTab';
import FourthTab from './tabs/FourthTab';
import FifthTab from './tabs/FifthTab'
const BottomTabNav = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    FirstTab,
    SecondTab,
    ThirdTab,
    FourthTab,
    FifthTab
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'FirstTab',
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(BottomTabNav);
```

on render :

```
      render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor: 'white'}}>

        <Text style={{paddingTop:20}}>Text on the Top of BottomTab Navigator</Text>

        <BottomTabNav/> 

      </View>

    )
  }
}
```

output image:

[image: BottomTab inside React Component]